# How to redirect a 404 route to Home using vue router in Vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

Hello almighty community!

I have a little problem with Vue.js 3. In the router, I'm unable to define that any unknown route should be redirected to "/".

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
 {
    path: "/*",
    redirect: "/",
  }
]
```

Here, I have tested the **redirect: "/"** works, but **path: "/*"** is not working. Path "/*" works only for domain.com/*... I have also tested **path: "*"** but I get this error:

> "Uncaught Error: Route "*" should be "/*"."

How do you do a 404 redirect in the latest Vue.js3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vue router 4 which is compatible with Vue 3 you can [Catch all / 404 Not found Route](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#catch-all-404-not-found-route) as follows:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
    redirect: "/",
  }
]
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-router-4-reproduction-forked-o9h0yh?file=/index.html)**

Comment: why do you import ´¨    createWebHashHistory if not in use ?